# Configuring "RequireHttpsAttribute" filter to account for X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, load-balancing

I am hosting a ASP.NET Framework application on AWS elastic bean, and I am using a load balancer.

Using my current configuration to require https results in infinite loops because the load balancers are using http to communicate with the server. In order to have my filter function i need to account for the X-Forwarded-Proto Header, which from my understanding contains the original requests protocol.
I do understand what is wrong, but I not understand how I can use this attribute in order to ensure a secure connection.

This is my current config:

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute {

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public RequireHttpsAttribute()
    {
        Port = 443;
    }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;

            if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get || request.Method == HttpMethod.Head)
                {
                    var uri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
                    uri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
                    uri.Port = this.Port;

                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found;
                    response.Headers.Location = uri.Uri;
                }
                else
                {
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                }

                actionContext.Response = response;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }
        }
}
```

This filter config is added to my WebApiConfig.

My question is:
How do check for the X-Forwarded-Proto in this filter?

Comment: I just noticed a comment in the Microsoft Documentation for RequireHttpsAttribute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio

It seems like this kind of implementation is meaningless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your load balancers are handling SSL for you, you'd *cede* that restriction (SSL only) to them - as you have noticed, your app will always detect `http:80` (not `https:443`).

> Do not use RequireHttpsAttribute on Web APIs that receive sensitive
>   information. RequireHttpsAttribute uses HTTP status codes to redirect
>   browsers from HTTP to HTTPS. *API clients may not understand or obey
>   redirects from HTTP to HTTPS.* Such clients may send information over
>   HTTP. Web APIs should either:
>
> - Not listen on HTTP.
> - Close the connection with status code 400 (Bad> Request) and not serve the request.

The note in the doc is saying that **API** clients may/may not follow your redirect response, so it's recommended that you respond with some error (nor not at all) - and is where you should check on the `http` headers. In your case, you can't do the first because your app will always get HTTP:80 (hence only the `http` header check/filter).

In an MVC site you can do routing redirects (Url Rewrite, etc), but that works because the clients are browsers (and know what do with a `redirect`). An API client however, can be *anything* (not just browsers).

---

Update/clarification:

Of course it's important so you *should* still filter the `http header` forwarded by your load balancer(s) that indicate whether or not the origin request was via `https` or not and follow the recommendation in doc - respond with an appropriate `http` error code (the note suggests `400 Bad Request`).

What you can't do is check the actual scheme/protocol of the origin request because your load balancers will *always forward* `http:80` to your app.

TLDR: you restrict based on http header info forwarded by your load balancer(s).

Comment: I think I understand.
My API client is only browsers at the moment. No plans for anything else just yet.
The load balancers are handling the SLL for me, and the site calling them is secured.
Would my app now be considered secure?
I get the impression that doing security checks for incoming requests is important.
However, i know the requests are coming from a secure connection to my balancers.